# Pyglet Subclass object has no attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyglet

I am working on a game in pyglet, this is the first time, although normally I use pygame

I am trying to subclass in pyglet.

```
class menu(pyglet.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(menu, self).__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.labels = {}


class pause_menu(menu):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(pause_menu, self).__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.labels['resume'] = pyglet.text.Label('Resume Game', font_name='Times New Roman', font_size=36, x=window.main.width//2, y=window.main.height//2)
```

I am getting this error

```
File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pyglet\sprite.py", line 225, in __init__
self._texture = img.get_texture()
AttributeError: 'pause_menu' object has no attribute 'get_texture' 'get_texture'.
```

What is going on? Am I using super wrong?

BTW:
The class is being called from another module

```
pause_menu = menu.pause_menu(x=0, y=0, batch=menu_batch, img=None)
```

Comment: Do you mean remove self from __init__(self, *args, **kwargs), that came up with the same error

Comment: You use it in *two* places, one of which is never called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are invoking the parent `__init__` wrong; use `super(menu, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)`. The method is *bound* for you by `super()`.

You also misnamed `menu.__init__`, missing a double underscore at the end.

```
class menu(pyglet.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(menu, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.labels = {}

class pause_menu(menu):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(pause_menu, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.labels['resume'] = pyglet.text.Label('Resume Game', font_name='Times New Roman', font_size=36, x=window.main.width//2, y=window.main.height//2)
```

Because you passed in `self` explicitly, the `pyglet.sprite.Sprite.__init__()` is called with **two** positional arguments, both references to `self`.

As a result, that second `self` argument is seen as the [`img` argument](http://www.pyglet.org/doc/api/pyglet.sprite.Sprite-class.html#__init__) and `pyglet` tries to call the [`AbstractImage.get_texture()` method](http://www.pyglet.org/doc/api/pyglet.image.AbstractImage-class.html#get_texture) on it.

Comment: Define 'still not working'? Do you get the same exception still? Or do you get a different exception now? If you got the exact same exception, are you certain you saved your source file and restarted the python script? What happens if you introduce an extra 'print()' line somewhere?

Comment: Same exception, if I add a print line just before the super all I get is hello and the error

Comment: No, is the *traceback* still the same? Is it caused in the same location?

Comment: The original _traceback_ pointed to the super in the pause_menu class now it points at the super in the menu class. Yes I remove both double self's.

Comment: And `pause_menu` is still part of the traceback, right? The exception still claims that the line `img.get_texture()` gives an attribute error on `get_texture` for the `pause_menu` type? Then the first argument is still the `pause_menu` instance, so **something** is passing in the extra argument.

Comment: Think I got it, pyglet does not allow the image to be none

Comment: Indeed, you do *have* to pass in an image for sprites. :-)